# Get Liferay's current user when integrate with spring web flow

Tags: spring, liferay, spring-webflow

Spring web flows introduced a variable currentUser which returns the authenticated principal user. In Liferay this always return as null and hence it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the authenticated Liferay user, you can always call:

```
PortalUtil.getUser(portletRequest);
```